# How to mine continuously in segtest with version bitcoin-0.20?

Tags: bitcoind, regtest, signet

I am just learning the bitcoin codes for version bitcoin-0.20 and I make it successfully.
Additionally, I have only one PC. I want to mine continuously in segtsest, however I only found methods below:

```
 == Generating ==
    generatetoaddress nblocks "address" ( maxtries )
    generatetodescriptor num_blocks "descriptor" ( maxtries )
```

But these methods can't mine continuously. Hence, would you please tell me how to mine continuously in segtest using version bitcoin-0.20?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean regtest? You'll need to continuously call this functions in a loop, but why would you want that? Alternatively, you can use external mining software using the GBT protocol.

Comment: Do you mean `regtest` or `signet`?

Comment: I mean  regtest.

Comment: thank you very much.  would you please tell me the name of the external mining software using the GBT protocol ?

Comment: my aim is to verify some function of bitcoin in regtest.thank you .

Comment: I just want to  simulate miner continuously of maintest.